# Html form button functionality to single button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I got a script on a website that reads html from a text file each time I press a button. The text file is chosen depending on what name of the page is given. It works fine and dandy with a  tag and  working as a button inside of it.

The problem I have is that I do not want the  and  tags at all if I want only one button, I have tried to call the script with jQuery and ajax in various ways without any luck.

Heres the website(its real basic for testing purposes):

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>PHP Flat File Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php include("savedinfo.php"); ?> 

// This is how it works, its fine for multiple buttons in a row
<form method="get">
<button type="submit" name="page" value="index" action="savedinfo.php">Index</button>
<button type="submit" name="page" value="page1" action="savedinfo.php">Page1</button>
<button type="submit" name="page" value="page2" action="savedinfo.php">Page2</button>
</form>

//But this is the way I'd like to create a button(not exact properties but in one line)
<input id="pageBtn" type="button" page="page1" value="page1"  /> 

</body>
```

What it does is simply update an region of the website with html from different text files without reloading the page.

The script that loads the html:

```
<?php    

//the script gets a name for a file(page) to load
$page = $_GET["page"];
//if it got no parameters(i.e. first load of the page, goto index)
if($page == null){
    $page = "index";
}

//check if the file/page exists, othervise display error page
if(file_exists($page.".txt"))
    $filename = $page.".txt";
else
    $filename = "404.txt";

$f = fopen($filename,"rt");
$content = fread($f, filesize($filename));
// send back the read html
echo $content;
@fclose($f);

?>
```

The text file page is just a plain  tag and some text that differs from page to page.

Now is it even possible to use a script or something to get rid of the  tags if you want to create a button that sends the name data to the script and updating the current page with the new info?

Comment: show your attempt at using jquery and ajax as that is what you are saying is your problem

Comment: lessen your code to the code your having trouble with, we won't build a website for you.

Comment: Well the code was mostly to show what I'm trying to achieve, the problem was getting rid of the <form> tags to get the same functionality on a button, you can check my comment on the answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attribute action belongs to element form

```
<form action="savedinfo.php">
```

Form element input has to be inside of form

```
<form method="get">
    <button type="submit" name="page" value="index" action="savedinfo.php">Index</button>
    <button type="submit" name="page" value="page1" action="savedinfo.php">Page1</button>
    <button type="submit" name="page" value="page2" action="savedinfo.php">Page2</button>

     <input id="pageBtn" type="button" page="page1" value="page1"  />
```

Instead of opening, reading and closing of file you may use file_get_contents. It will give you content of chosen file too.

If you need only change and then export content of chosen file somewhere to screen, use

```
<a href="?page=filename">description of page</a>
```

and then you need to make process of manipulation with chosen file safe. But it is something you should do by yourself.

But really, nobody cannot make anything instead you. We (at least me) may help with great many things, but ... this is all I can help with.

BTW: It is better to have content of pages in any DB, than in files - if it is not really needed to have it in file.

Best regards.

Comment: Yea well, thanks anyways. The <a href link would kinda work, when I tested myself `<a href="index.php" name="page" value="index">`did work as a button, I'm going to check how to do the formatting of the text with classes later. But thanks!